# Issue with JSON Deserialization and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string using VB.net and cannot seem to pull the values out of the finished List. Here is the simple class:

```
Public Class Personinformation

Private theName As String
Private thePic As String

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Name = theName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        theName = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Picture() As String
    Get
        Picture = thePic
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        thePic = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Then in the Page_Load I have inserted the following:

```
Dim JSONstring As String = "[{""Name"":""John"",""Picture"":""mypic.jpg""}]"
Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim outputinfo = json.Deserialize(Of List(Of Personinformation))(JSONstring)
```

Now I am lost because I can't seem to get the name/value pairs. I tried doing this

```
Response.Write(outputinfo.Item(1))
```

I am told "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON array only has one item in it but you are accessing the second item of a 0 based list.

```
Response.Write(outputinfo.Item(0))
```

Should work for you.